# Changing URL from an iFrame: setTimeout changes how window.location works?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My `iframe` contains a link that should change the hash/trigger an event in the parent.

How come this code won't work:

```
<!-- in iframe -->
<a href="#" onClick="parent.navigate();return false;">Link</a>
```

```
// in parent
  function navigate() {
    window.location.href = '#anchor';
  }
```

But this does:

```
<!-- in iframe -->
<a href="#" onClick="parent.navigate();return false;">Link</a>
```

```
// in parent
  function navigate() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = '#anchor';
    }, 0); 
  }
```

Comment: In the second version of `navigate()`, what happens if you do `var _window = window;` before the setTimeout and then `alert(_window === window);` inside the setTimeout?

Comment: Also, in the first `onClick`, you have a wayward `'` character. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: Sorry about that; typo in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an issue with the context that the navigate() function is in, with `window` being in the context of the iframe.

Try setting you navigate method to use `top.location.href` instead, for example:

```
// in parent
  function navigate() {
    top.location.href = '#anchor';
  }
```

or alternatively, in your iframe, call `parent.window.location.href = '#anchor'`

Answer (score 0):

@am not i am's comment that you have an apostrophe is likely the cause

Even the code highlighter is showing different highlights because of it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, edited the question to fix my mistake.  This was a typo in the question, but I'm still seeing this behavior on my site.